# How to reference an ${ENV} var in a propertyConfigurer bean?

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, production-environment

I'm trying to modify [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) for my own purposes.

I want to load the properties from a server-specific file, using something like this:

```
<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="locations">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>${ENV_JDBC_CONFIG}</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Where `ENV_JDBC_CONFIG` is an enrivonment variable specifying a path to a properties file.

This fails with

```
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/${ENV_JDBC_CONFIG}]`
```

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: You must add file protocol before full file path to locate the resource.for ex if you referring D:/MyProject/Db.properties you should write it as file:///D:/MyProject/Db.properties,by the way you should also mention <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"></property> if it is required to search in System properties.Is this app will be deployed in app server?check for logs like this :Loading properties file from URL [file:/D:/MyProject/Db.properties].I have tried this in glassfish 4.1 & it is working.I have added ENV_JDBC_CONFIG in server system properties.

Comment: Does using `<beans:value>${env.ENV_JDBC_CONFIG}</beans:value>` make a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring throws a misleading error message when the variable referenced in `${}` is not defined.

In this case it told me FileNotFound when in fact the variable was not defined (with that exact spelling, anyway).

The fix was to add `-DENV_JDBC_CONFIG=file:/blah/blah/blah` in `/etc/defaults/tomcat7`

Answer (score 0):

Use systemPropertiesMode property of the configurer to use System properties.
check [this article](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring), it tells you tips to manage external properties.

If you want to use env variable inside other bean definition you could use it like

`<bean id="yourBean" class="com.company.YourBean">
    <property name="environment" value="#{ systemProperties['env.var1'] }"/>
    <!-- other properties goes here....-->
</bean>`